# Test UseReactiveVar with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, apollo-client

I am using apollo-client-3 for state management. I want to test `useReactiveVar`.

Here is my code:

```
import { useReactiveVar } from '@apollo/client';

const showBoxVar = makeVar(false);
const App: FunctionComponent = () => {

    const showBox = useReactiveVar(showBoxVar);
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {showBox && <Box/> }

            <SomeComponent />

        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

I want to test that once showBox is true, Box renders. How to do that?

Answer (score -2):

You can mock them like below

```
jest.mock('@apollo/client', () => {
  return {
    useReactiveVar: () => true,
    makeVar: jest.fn(() => null)
  }
});
```

Comment: This solution only works if you have a component with a single `useReactiveVar`. It does not work for complex components.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors Do you know how to make it work with multiple?